# Clear Token googlesheets package

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-api

I am using the googlesheets package in R.

To sign-in, I would use the function:

```
library(googlesheets)
googlesheets::gs_auth()
```

I am looking for something similar to the gmailr package where I can do the following:

```
gmailr::clear_token()
gmailr::gmail_auth()
```

How do I clear this token in the googlesheets package specifically so that I can authenticate to a different google account?

Is there a function that does this in the package?

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

need to use the function:

```
gs_deauth(clear_cache = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```